# How to debug Worklight iOS app or phonegap iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have read these article

1. http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/
2. http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/

   but i cant to able to see my app under
   **Develop-->Device name-->myApp**.
   But i could able to debug blank safari browser.Could anyone suggest how to debug the iOS app in chrome or safari? Whether i have to change any app setting like in android **android-debuggable:true**?

Answer (score 0):

Worklight is not based on Telerik, so following their tutorials is kinda moot.

If you have an application running in a device and you would like to debug is using the Inspector tool that Apple's Safari browser provides, follow these steps:

1. Make sure that the application you've installed on the device was built to the device from Xcode, and is not from a production build (i.e. the App Store) - otherwise it will not be available in the Safari Inspector. Also that it is connected via USB to the Mac...
2. Make sure you have enable the Inspector tool. In Safari > Preferences > Advanced > tick the checkbox for "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
3. Now that 1 & 2 have been verified, go to Safari > Develop > your-device > your-app

Comment: Same i followed. I am using Worklight 6.0 But i cant see my app in device ( Safari --> Develop --> Device --> App). But if i open safari i could able to see that. Is any problem with worklight version ?

Comment: No. This works fine for me and it's got nothing to do with Worklight.

Comment: I have to enable debug in iOS app ? like android-debuggable:true in android. Because i followed your steps, still i am not getting. One good thing i can able to debug Android App. I am using Sencha touch (2.2.1) + worklight (6.0).

Comment: There is no 'debug' mode to enable in iOS.

Comment: @Idan.Adar, No. Even our team cant move further. If u have some blog please share.

Comment: @Idan.Adar.. I can able to debug in iphone simualtor but i could able to do in Device.

Comment: In iOS, make sure the Settings.app > Safari > Advanced > web inspector is enabled. Then from Safari in make, check if the app from the iOS device is available.

Comment: Yeah its set. no change in that. still i cant do remote debugging only with iOS device. Even its in developer profile.